# Custom Spinner Adapter

Tags: android

I wanted to apply a custom font to my spinner. The only way i found out is that to create a custom adapter. Here is my code

```
    private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<CharSequence> itemList;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<CharSequence> itemList) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context=context;
        this.itemList=itemList;
    }

    public TextView getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView v = (TextView) super
                .getView(position, convertView, parent);
        Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/gilsanslight.otf");
        v.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
        v.setText(itemList.get(position));
        return v;
    }

    public TextView getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView v = (TextView) super
                .getView(position, convertView, parent);
        Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/gilsanslight.otf");
        v.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
        v.setText(itemList.get(position));
        return v;
    }

}
```

Then i use

```
List<CharSequence> itemList = new ArrayList<CharSequence>(
            Arrays.asList(items));

    mySpinnerArrayAdapter = new   CustomAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,itemList); 
    spinner.setAdapter(mySpinnerArrayAdapter);
```

After doing this, my adapter is empty. Can anyone please help me ? The items contains a list of countries.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Try

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(yourRowlayout, parent,
                    false);
       TextView make = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Make);
        Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/gilsanslight.otf");
        v.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
        v.setText(itemList.get(position));
        return row;
    }


public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View row = inflater.inflate(yourRowlayout, parent,
                        false);
           TextView make = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Make);
            Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/gilsanslight.otf");
            v.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
            v.setText(itemList.get(position));
            return row;
        }
```

Comment: You can get the inflator just once in the constructor, and then reuse after that.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using a custom Adapter, but using setDropDownResource instead?

Comment: I would also recommend doing a check on convertview and only inflating if convertview == null, since that is what ArrayAdapters do internally, for efficiency's sake.

Comment: You can use viewHolder pattern in this adapter for smooth scrolling

Comment: Params of both are the same and also the body. So, why don't call from getView to getDropDownView? or viceversa? DRY

Comment: Thanks for `getDropDownView()`. Strange, but many tutorials skip this method. In my case when spinner expanded it showed item.toString() instead of a string (field) inside the item. A agree with @ValMartinez, you can refactor the code and extract a method of creation a `TextView` or even call `getView()` from `getDropDownView()`.

Answer (score 4):

Pass itemList as parameter in super class constructor

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,List<CharSequence> itemList) {

    super(context, textViewResourceId, itemList);
    this.context=context;
    this.itemList=itemList;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this out**

Inside your Layout File:

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinnerview"
     android:layout_width="180dp"
     android:layout_height="42dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
     android:background="@drawable/spinner_back"
     android:paddingLeft="5dp"
     android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
     android:visibility="visible" />
```

inside your `string.xml` :

```
 <string-array name="spinner_array_environtment">
        <item>Test</item>
        <item>Production</item>
 </string-array>
```

inside you Java File in `onCreate()` Method:

```
spinner_environment = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerview);
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                    R.array.spinner_array_environtment, R.layout.spinner);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner);
            spinner_environment.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Make new `spinner.xml` file to your layout folder :

inside `spinner.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textColor="#4C4646" />
```

Thats it!!!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, I think :)

```
List<String> listOfItems = getListOfItems(); // returns ArrayList<String>

ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfItems);

targetSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Ok, to simply put a list of string in a spinner shouldn't force us to implement an Adapter. That's a code blot and getting a bit pattern crazy, I think.

Trick is the simple_spinner_item id - damn, I like the R.id mechanism but this isn't intuitive from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (ussing android.R.layout.**simple_spinner_dropdown_item**):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    checkedTextView.setText(itemList.get(position));
    return checkedTextView;
}
```

i think it's a better solution because you don't inflate multiple times.

Comment: Actually, the simple_spinner_dropdown_item is inflated multiple times anyway, so why not inflate your custom view...