# Change item layout in multiple spinner in android

Tags: android

I use Multiple spinner from this post: [Android Spinner with multiple choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice)

but I want to change looks of items. I have my own layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/radiobutton2" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@android:color/black">
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to change items layout on my own layout. How I can do that?

Comment: Create your custom adapter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599703/custom-spinner-adapter/12599800