# I want to give effect to popup of spinner

Tags: android

I was trying to change the android spinner popup window. Is there any way I can change it? 
My spinner Object like

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.languagespinner);

String[] languages = { "English", "French", "Swahili", "Russian",
        "Bahasa" };
int[] flags = { R.drawable.us, R.drawable.france, R.drawable.sa,
        R.drawable.russia, R.drawable.timor_leste };
for(int i = 0; i < languages.length; i++){
    HashMap<String, Object> dummy = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    dummy.put("lang", languages[i]);
    dummy.put("flag", flags[i]);

    data.add(dummy);
}

String from[] = {"lang", "flag"};
int to[] = {R.id.lang, R.id.flag};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.customspinner, from, to);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My custom layout contains the flag and text for language. If you want to give an even more customized look and feel, I would advice you to use a custom adapter. [This](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-spinner-in-android/28286) is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a custom adapter class extending `ArrayAdapter`. That adapter has a `getView()` method where you can inflate your own layout for every item in the spinner, thus changing the looks of the spinner dropdown items. 
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599703/custom-spinner-adapter) question.