# how to create custom spinner in android with image, text?

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, spinner

Anyone please guide me for creating custom spinner in android that should be dynamic data .

Comment: Use Custom adapter for spinner

Comment: can u provide code for this .if possible i am new to android.

Comment: Hello Refer this answer already given http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599703/custom-spinner-adapter

Comment: this is not helpful if possible provide code relate to the question.

Comment: please follow below example which contain code  http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For taking textview and image in spinner you have to use custom adapter for that please follow below example link which is helpful for you for create custom adapter

http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107

if you have any query then feel free to comment

Answer (score 1):

Set a boolean value with each of your dataset.
next, write a custom Adapter that extends an ArrayAdapter

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(YourActivity.this, yourList);
```

Inside the CustomAdapter override the getView methode and inflate a layout in it.That layout can contain imageview,textview and checkbox.

It will look like this

```
  public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.veg_item,  parent, false);

    //your code here

    return convertView;
}
```

Set that adapter to your spinner.

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Create a boolean called prevBoolean inside your activity.
Now you can use a boolean value with each of your data set, Whenever the checkbox is checked,try this,

```
currentDataset.boolean=true;
if(prevBoolean!=null)
prevBoolean=false;
prevBoolean=currrentdataset.boolean;
```

,Inside the getview() method, if the boolean is checked, set

```
checkbox.setChecked(true);
```

else

```
checkbox.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna explain you briefly what basic approach you require to implement what you want.

First , you need a custom adapter to set for your spinner something like this,

```
    public static class CityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CityInfo> {
        private Activity context;
        List<CityInfo> data;

        public CityAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<CityInfo> data, int hidingItemIndex) {
            super(context, resource, data);
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
        // Ordinary view in Spinner, we use android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
         // This view starts when we click the spinner.
            View row = convertView;


                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_items, parent, false);

            CityInfo item = data.get(position); //CityInfo is a bean/model class

            if (item != null) {   
            // Parse the data from each object and set it.
                TextView myCity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv1);

              //do other stuffs here

            }


            return row;
        }
}
```

CityInfo bean class will be something like this,

```
public class CityInfo {
private String cityName;
private int cityId;

public void setCityName(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}

public void setCityId(int cityId){
    this.cityId = cityId;
}

public int getCityId(){
    return cityId;
}





public String toString() {
    return cityName;
}
```

}

And inside `onCreate` of your activity assuming that you are accessing the spinner do this,

```
 /*adapter for spinner to show city list*/
    cityAdapter = new CityAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_items, feedItemsCityNames, 0);

    // attaching city adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
```

Set all the `TextView`,`ImageView` or `RadioButton` etc in the `spinner_items.xml` and access them accordingly inside custom adapter.

`feedItemsCityNames` is an `ArrayList<CityInfo>` type array list which holds the updated data retrieved from server.

Hope you get a clear idea from this example.

Comment: but i want image, text and radio button either check box inside spinner.how to do that ..please provide me code.

Comment: the way i added textview  inside custom adapter , likewise add code for image , radiobutton etc. This is not a site where people will give you the exact code what you want. If this answer helped you , please accept it and upvote it.