# Android - how do I change the color of the spinner itself?

Tags: android, user-interface, styles, spinner, android-spinner

All of my searches has led me to guides on how to change the text color of the spinner choices, but how do I change the color of the text and arrow on the spinner itself?

[image]

Here's a snip of my spinner. It's supposed to say "Mercury".

Here's my attempt at the style. It did change the arrow to white, but not the text. I only applied it to the spinner since it will mess up the rest of the activity.

```
<style name="Theme.LightText2" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

UPDATE: I tried to apply it to the activity itself via the manifest and it worked, but it's messed up the rest of my activity.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599703/custom-spinner-adapter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this do one thing , Take one textview and set arrow icon on right(Drawableright) customize your text text view as you wont and on click open dialog with single selection and on item selected set text to textview

Answer (score 0):

Create array adapter which will inflate `TextView` from `Layout_resource`
then set your color to inflated `TextView`

```
your_spinnersp.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(context,R.layout.txt_spinner,lst_data));
```

in layout add TextView

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="8dp" android:textSize="16sp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android :textColor="#ffff00"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and use spnrSelect.performClick(); on click of rlSpinner to open spinner

```
              <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rlSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/scale_20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_1dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:clickable="true">

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spnrSelect"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:dropDownWidth="@dimen/scale_300dp"
                        android:scrollbars="none"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtSelect"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/scale_1dp"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/scale_1dp"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/scale_1dp"
                        android:text="@string/txtSelect"
                        android:textColor="@color/edt_hint"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/edt_hint"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/spnrDownArrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/scale_10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow_icon"
                        android:rotation="90" />

                </RelativeLayout>
```