# Android studio prevent spinner from changing selected text

Tags: android

I have a `ViewPager` with a `Spinner` in one of the pages as shown below.

[image]

When the `Spinner` is clicked:

[image]

When I click on on `My Calendar` item, it swipes automatically to the `MY CALENDAR` tab. However, when I swipe back to the `MY PAGES` tab, the item selected is `My Calendar` since it was clicked, as shown below.

[image]

But I want the text to not change if the item selected is either `My Calendar` or `Contact`. Is this possible?

Comment: paste your code please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your custom Spiner adapter, that will not display text changes. It's pretty simple to do. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599703/custom-spinner-adapter)